# Login to ssh session and afterwards automatically look for and access existing screen session?

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu-screen, sshpass

I would like to connect to a server using ssh and after logging in I would like to automatically execute

```
screen -R
```

My script looks as follows:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -t name@server.cheese 'screen -R; bash -l'
```

It is important that I would like to be able to control from the outside which commands are executed after login. Else I could most likely just add stuff the ".bashrc" or some equal file.

Comment: your query is not quite clear, what is it you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: The 'screen -R' command retrieves a running screen session to continue it. When I execute the command as above it isn't able to find this screen session and instead starts a new. Still I can kill this session and afterwards access my existing old one. So I assume the reason is the execution order. I would like to know how I can fix my command so that it finds the running screen session bound to my account?

Comment: screen -ls && screen -R
This should do the trick. But this will only work if you have one detached session. may be you can tweak this by wrapping around shell script.

Comment: I tried it and it prints out the detached session of mine but then it ignores the 'screen -R' completely...

Comment: yeah so the exit code for screen works differently in linux flavour. With ubuntu flavour this would work. Please do check answer posted by me.

Comment: Can you force detach and reattach?  When I was regularly using `screen` I would (manually) execute `screen -d -R -S <session name>`, so does simply using `screen -d -R` fulfill your needs?  Or can you provide a named session that you'll always be wanting to reattach to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -tt user@server 'screen -ls 2>/dev/null | grep -i detached && screen -r || echo "No screen detached sessions found"'
```

This would work provided you have one screen detached.

Comment: It does it perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

check your ssh config? for example:

```
grep PermitTTY /etc/ssh/config
grep PermitTTY ~/.ssh/config
```

If they are not set to YES, maybe that's your problem?

PS: any reason to not use tmux instead of screen? Just curious.

Comment: Yeah, tmux isn't installed on the server I am accessing, the admin prefers screen.

Comment: '/etc/ssh/config' as well as '~/.ssh/config' do not exist or I am not able to see them but still get the message that they do not exist